# Mounted image appears empty in Finder

Tags: disk-utility, dmg

I decided to reinstall MacOS X from scratch.

I have rebooted my mac with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then used Disk Utility to create a `.dmg` disk image on a USB drive.

I then rebooted the computer and verified that I could mount the disk image. It took some time to verify it (250 GB), but it finally mounted fine and I could see that all files were there.

I then rebooted with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again, formatted the internal hard drive, and reinstalled MacOS 10.10.

Now when I reconnect the USB drive and remount the disk image (skipping the verification), although <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> says that it's almost full (2 out of 250 GB left), it seems to only contain a handful of empty folders: Application, Library, System, Users.

Using Finder, it's just as if all my data was lost.

However when using Terminal, I can browse the entire drive: all the files are there, and I am able to copy them back to my internal drive using `cp`.

**Why does Finder show empty directories?** Is this a consequence of skipping disk verification?

Comment: Finder display is asynchronous, and sometimes a folder image refresh slides so far down the priority queue that it disappears. Try restarting Finder (cmd opt esc for dialog).

Comment: I have restarted the mac entirely, but same result!

Comment: Restarting Mac brings up all network devices as well. A Finder restart alone *may* give you different results. In my experience, the whole thing is kind of dodgy, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Restarting finder did help me (could not see contents of DMGs and some folders, event though those were on my internal SSD).